# Open Comment form with a click

Tags: jquery, forms, comments

I am trying to make the wordpress comment form not showing in whole all the time, but to open when clicking on a button.
The below code I am trying works great. The only problem is that by clicking you get to the top of the page and then need to scroll down below the post to see the form. Any suggestions on how to pass this?

```
<a href="#" ID="Leave_a_comment">Leave a Comment</a>
<div id="comment_form_wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Leave_a_comment').click(function() {
            $('#comment_form_wrapper').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#Leave_a_comment').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#comment_form_wrapper').show();
   });
});
```

Comment: What if I would like to hide the comment form with a second click?

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollTop` with  `offset` after anchor tag click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Leave_a_comment').click(function() {
        $('#comment_form_wrapper').show();
        $(window).scrollTop($('#comment_form_wrapper').offset().top);
        });
 });
```